# formal smoothness and cotangent complex

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, deformation-theory, cotangent-complex

If $k$ is a field and $A$ is a formally smooth $k$-algebra, then we know that $\Omega^{1}_{A/k}$ is projective. What about its cotangent complex $L_{A/k}$? When is it quasi-isomorphic to $\Omega^{1}_{A/k}$ put in degree zero? If $A$ is noetherian, it is always true, by Popescu's theorem and the reduction to the finite type case.

In general, I would expect to be wrong but is it true in the intermediate case where $A=colim B_i$ where the $B_i$'s are $k$-algebra of finite type with smooth transition maps?

Comment: The cotangent functor is left Quillen, so $\mathbb{L}_{\varinjlim B_i} \simeq \varinjlim (\mathbb{L}_{B_i}\otimes_{B_i}^{\mathbf{L}}A)$. Taking all the transition maps to be smooth, that makes the ind-smooth case OK.

Comment: transition maps are smooth but  one $B_i$ could be singular, so that every other $B_j$ has the same singularities as $B_i$.